# ubuntu one saying i have wrong email or password even though i have triple checked and reset password?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I am trying to install an application in ubuntu software and it asks me for my ubuntu one info (first time install) and I enter my info correctly and it still says i am entering the wrong email or password. I have even tried reseting my password to make sure i didn't misspell the password.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change your password by doing

```
sudo passwd <username>
```

If it says you are not part of the sudoers file you can ask the system owner. If you are the owner you have to boot into recovery mode. [How to enter recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)